# In Rails, can I put views in the 'vendor' directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, I have some views (layouts, partials) that I want to put in `vendor/views` and `vendor/views/layouts` instead of `app/views`. But, it's implied by the guides (and the base project structure) that only `assets` and `plugins` are put in `vendor`. Still, can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I once did manipulate the view_path, where Rails is looking for the views. I did it because I needed to have two versions of the views. So the way you could do it is manipulating

ActionController::Base.view_paths = ["app/views", "app/views/my_app", "app/views/your_app"]
or
ActionController::Base.prepend_view_path "app/views/my_app"

But as mentioned in this [Blog Post](http://www.axehomeyg.com/2009/06/10/view-path-manipulation-for-rails-with-aop/), you should not because it is really expensive (the code is taken from this post). If you read further in the post, there is a solution provided. Maybe this helps for a start point.